# Get a Django List - Dict in javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I have the following problem with Django. I am sending a List to Javascript and I spect to get this result in the browser. Instance of this looks like my code ignore everything what I do.

My code looks like this

view.py

```
import itertools

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
import json

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


class UsageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'overview.html'


def getFTest(request):
    .....

    context = {"Features": dataFeature}
    json_context = json.dumps(context)
    return render(request, "overview.html",  {"context_array" : json_context})
```

url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views_ import index, getFTest

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index, name="home"),
    path('overview', LicUsageView.as_view(), name="overview"),
    path('', getFTest, name="getFTest"),
]
```

overview.html

```
var test = ["{{ context_array|safe }}"];
console.log(test);
```

result from the console:
an empty List

[image]

Can somebody tell me where my error ist? Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

You have two paths with as path pattern `''`, so that means that if you visit `''`, it will always use the `index` view, and *not* `getFTest`, as a result it will thus not render the template with the `context_array`, and thus result in rendering an empty string.

You thus should set `getFTest` to render with the root path, or set up a different path pattern:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views_ import index, getFTest

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', getFTest, name='getFTest'),  # ← use getFTest
    path('overview', LicUsageView.as_view(), name="overview"),
]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But what I do to send then this specific information to my templates overview.html when I have already a Path with ' ' for index, home.html and I have one with 'overview' to load the template as_view(). Now I need to send information to overview.html template, but "overview" is already in use between my Path() definition

Comment: @zgrizzly_7: well that is not possible. The idea is that when you fetch a URL, then you trigger *one* view, not multiple. A view does not per se needs to render a template, and it can render multiple templates to combine text, but the idea is that the template thus returns a HTTP response. Templates are only a tool to make it more convenient to generate text, but you thus have always *one view per request*.

Comment: ok, I think I understand more and more how Django is working, but any suggestion to solve this problem? 2 differents requests for one template

Comment: @zgrizzly_7: if you want to pass the data through a different channel, yes. This is basically what a lot of sites do through AJAX calls. If the data is passed together with the index, why not update the `index` view, and include the data to render it.

Comment: yes, exactly what I was thinking. With a AJAX call is working. Thank you very much!